# NoInitialContextException when connecting to JNDI on glassFish server

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

Am trying to code a JMS application, I used the glassFish admin page to build a ConnectionFactory and Qeueu ,I want to know how to let my application know about the jndi built on the server to be able to send messages.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestJMS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter JMS Client Type");

        if (input.equals("1")) {
            QueueConnection queueConnection = null;

            try {


                Context context = new InitialContext();
                QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");

                String queueName = "jms/Queue";

                Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup(queueName);

                queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
                QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);

                TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage();
                message.setText("This is a TextMessage");
                queueSender.send(message);
                System.out.println("Message sent.");

            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Naming Exception");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("JMS Exception");
            } finally {
                if (queueConnection != null) {
                    try {
                        queueConnection.close();
                    } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }}}
```

am getting the exception

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initialNaming Exception

    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at TestJMS.main(TestJMS.java:37)
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at TestJMS.main(TestJMS.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a properties object when creating the InitialContext.  The properties object specifies the factory class and provider info (among other settings) needed for the connection to the specific back end server.

For example, for IBM WebSphere,

```
Properties p = new Properties();   
String conFact = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"l 
p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, conFact);
        p.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, <providerInfo>);
ic = new InitialContext(p);
```

For GlassFish, the will be a connection factory in the client jar that should be
specified when requesting the IC.

Here is a partial example from Oracle at 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0029/aeqba/index.html

```
Hashtable  env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///C:/imq_admin_objects");
Context  ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

Comment: getting the exception ...javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Comment: Did you review the above Oracle link?  What properties did you pass when creating InitialContext?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this error on **`Glassfish 5`**

I used this solution in the `maven` project, adding the dependency on `pom.xml`.

`Hashtable` was not neeeded.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.appclient/gf-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.appclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here my example like you initial code:

```
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        IServicioSumarRemote servicioSumarRemote = (IServicioSumarRemote)context.lookup("java:global/wsserver/ServicioSumarWSImpl!bz.soap.services.IServicioSumarRemote");
```